# Vintage mode workflow

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have just got started using VIM when realized that there is the Vintage Mode on Sublime Text. I would like to ask advanced users on how is their common commands and which they decide to use, for example for search, do you use the Vim command or Sublime Command? Also Navigating and Multiple Cursors.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: forget Vintage mode and just use Sublime.

Long answer: it's not that there is anything wrong with Vintage but it is essentially binding Vim keys to native Sublime methods. Therefore it's useful if you are coming from Vim but less so if you are just starting with it. If you want to use Vim, I would personally recommend you just use Vim (either Terminal or MacVim for instance). There are plenty of Vim syntaxes that just don't work in Vintage ('vip' springs to mind) so it makes more sense to get the full native experience of one or the other.

That's just my take obviously.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. That's exactly my doubt. Which syntaxes or commands doesn't work on Vintage that do work on Vim?